How do I add an argument to a FastAPI GET call
I am very new to Python and FastAPI. The application has tables with a retired_at datetime field and I am trying to add an argument to the get_all call to allow the user to include retired records in the response. Here is the code in the router:
   class CreateMyTableRequest(BaseModel):
       name: str
       organisation_id: UUID


   class CreateMyTableRequest(BaseModel):
       name: str
       organisation_id: UUID
    
    
   class GetMyTableResponse(UUIDModel, 
       TimestampModel, CreateMyTableRequest):
       pass

   @router.get(
       "/mytable",
       response_model=List[GetMyTableResponse],
       status_code=status.HTTP_200_OK,
   )
   async def get_all(
       current_user: Annotated[GetUserResponse, Depends(get_current_active_user)],
       async_session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db),
       include_retired: bool = False,
   ) -> List[GetMyTableResponse]:

All the code was developed and working before I began to work on this so all I have done is added the include_retired argument. It still works as expected when I run the FastAPI tests so long as I do not send a value for include_retired. However, when I try to send a value True for include_retired the program crashes.
My call is
response = await async_client.get(
    f"{settings.api_v1_prefix}/mytable",
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {authorization_token}"},
    include_retired = True,
)

The error is
E           TypeError: AsyncClient.get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'include_retired'
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?  I'm guessing it is something incredibly obvious but I just can't see it.
I've tried everything I can think of like moving the position of the argument in the definition or using *args, or **kwargs but at the current stage of my python experience, I may have been using them incorrectly. Almost everything I tried resulted in the same error message.

As I can see, include_retired is query param, so you should pass it by following code:
response = await async_client.get(
    f"{settings.api_v1_prefix}/mytable",
    headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {authorization_token}"},
    params={"include_retired": True},
)

